# Not able to navigate to the draweritem in drawernavigation

Tags: react-native

I am having a drawer navigation in my react native app in that drawer navigation on each click on drawer item a tab navigator open, every drawer item is working but when I navigate to first drawer item in my drawer then I am not able to navigate although every other drawer items are responding correctly.

```
    Home : {
        screen : TabsNavigator,
        navigationOptions : {
            drawerLabel : 'Home',
            drawerIcon : ({tintColor} ) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home-outline" size={RFValue(20)} color = {tintColor}/>
            )    
        }

    },

    Store : {
        screen : TabsNavigator,
        navigationOptions : {
            drawerLabel : 'Store',
            drawerIcon : ({tintColor} ) => (
                <FontAwesome name="location-arrow"  size={RFValue(20)} color = {tintColor}/>
            )    
        }
    },
    Members  : {
        screen : TabsNavigator,
        navigationOptions : {
            drawerLabel : 'Members',
            drawerIcon : ({tintColor} ) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-group"  size={RFValue(20)} color = {tintColor}/>
            )    
        }
    },
    Profile : {
        screen : TabsNavigator,
        navigationOptions : {
            drawerLabel : 'Profile',
            drawerIcon : ({tintColor} ) => (
                <AntDesign name="profile"  size={RFValue(20)} color = {tintColor}/>
            )    
        }
    },

},{
    drawerPosition : 'right',
    contentComponent : CustomDrawerComponent,

})
```

Comment: Show me the code that you set up your navigation and the code where you're going.

Comment: can't show you the code but I can explain what I am doing

Comment: If you do not provide the code, you will not be able to identify the problem.

Comment: I am editing the post and providing code of my navigation drawer see if you find something.Actually I have a login screen after login drawer navigator is loading and in drawer navigator each drawer item is loading tab navigator and inside each tab item a stack navigator is loading.When i move through navigator every item works fine but first item is not working properly.

Comment: The code you edited is a code that has nothing to do with move Screen